# CRAN-acceptable way of linking to OpenMP some C code called from Rcpp

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp

I’m building an R package that has some `.c` files with code that uses OpenMP, and these C functions are called from `.cpp` files, but the `.cpp` files themselves don’t make any use of OpenMP.

e.g.
 `cfile.c`:

```
int parallel_function(double *x, int n)
{   
    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(x, n)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ x[i] *= 2; }
}
```

`cppfile.cpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
extern “C” {
    int parallel_function(double *x, int n);
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void multiply_by_two(NumericVector x, int n){parallel_function(x.begin(), n);}
```

In order to enable OpenMP for the C files, my first though was to construct a `Makevars` like this, following the R extensions manual:

```
PKG_CFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
```

But that will throw me the following:

```
Check: use of SHLIB_OPENMP_*FLAGS in Makefiles, Result: NOTE
    src/Makevars: SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS is included in PKG_LIBS but linking is by C++
  Use of these macros is discussed in sect 1.2.1.1 of 'Writing R
  Extensions'. The macros for different languages may differ so the
  matching macro must be used in PKG_CXXFLAGS (etc) and match that used
  in PKG_LIBS (except for Fortran: see the manual).
```

So then, if I try instead:

```
PKG_CFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

I would get:

```
Check: use of SHLIB_OPENMP_*FLAGS in Makefiles, Result: NOTE
    src/Makevars: SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS is included in PKG_CFLAGS but not in PKG_LIBS
    src/Makevars: SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS is included in PKG_LIBS but not in PKG_CXXFLAGS
  Use of these macros is discussed in sect 1.2.1.1 of 'Writing R
  Extensions'. The macros for different languages may differ so the
  matching macro must be used in PKG_CXXFLAGS (etc) and match that used
  in PKG_LIBS (except for Fortran: see the manual).
```

Even if I use both flags like  this:

```
PKG_CFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
```

I would get:

```
Check: use of SHLIB_OPENMP_*FLAGS in Makefiles, Result: NOTE
    src/Makevars: SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS is included in PKG_LIBS but linking is by C++
    src/Makevars: it is not portable to include multiple SHLIB_OPENMP_*' macros in PKG_LIBS
  Use of these macros is discussed in sect 1.2.1.1 of 'Writing R
  Extensions'. The macros for different languages may differ so the
  matching macro must be used in PKG_CXXFLAGS (etc) and match that used
  in PKG_LIBS (except for Fortran: see the manual).
```

So, since the `.cpp` code does not require omp linkage, I’m wondering what would be the **correct and minimalist** way of linking the `.c` files but not the `.cpp` files.

Comment: See the comment I made to the answer by @coatless.  BTW I find anon handles off-putting.  You know who I am, and it give my help away for free.  Why do you hide?

Comment: Congrats! You found a bug in the R-devel version.

Comment: Not sure about a bug. New requirements for checks _always_ go to r-devel first.  Which is why we're asked to check r-release _and_ r-devel.  Whenever I attempt to think that "I know better, and R Core is wrong" I most often end up revising that view :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel : it's not available anymore - could you post it again as an answer?

Comment: @AnonAsker Done.  Also, why do you hide?

Comment: As for why I don’t use my real name, I don’t interact with the people here elsewhere, don’t like the idea of everything I ever say and do being public domain info associated to me, don’t want employers to find me here, and very much prefer the old times before facebook where no one used their real names. This is the first time I ask something for a topic that will later be linkable to me. Besides, I’ve already been using this account throughout SE sites for a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, we can mix C and C++ code in an R package.

Once OpenMP enters, CRAN now seems to stronly prefer consistent use of either `SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS` *or* `SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS`.

Now, given that `g++` will enter for linking, it would seem that you should use `SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS` throughout -- which suggests renaming your C files to be C++ files.

It all seems a little over the top, but that is what I would try.  And the CRAN checks are usually all there for a good reason so experience has taught most of to play along with them.

Comment: I don’t really like this approach, but it seems to be the only alternative in which CRAN wouldn’t complain.

Comment: key word from Dirk is "either" I don't understand this limitation, but it is stated in Writing R Extensions.