# How to resolve NoOMP flags from CRAN?

Tags: r, openmp, r-package, cran

I am submitting an R package to CRAN with C++ code. I've read and re-read Section 1.2.1.1 "OpenMP support" in the manual: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support

Based on this, I use conditionals for any OpenMP calls as follows:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
  #include <omp.h>
#endif

#ifdef _OPENMP
  omp_set_num_threads(n_cores);
#endif

#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
#endif

#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp critical
#endif
```

Unfortunately, CRAN still flags my package for violating OpenMP issues.

I'm stumped. Why would this be? Surely the conditionals resolve this issue, no? Have I misunderstood the manual?

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are these CRAN warnings exactly? And did you set the PKG flags in the Makevars file?

Comment: This is a very simple package with 4 *cpp files and Rcpp. There is no Makevars file which I'm using for them. As for the warnings, they were warnings after the package was accepted to CRAN and built.

Comment: No makevars file? Normally you should put a **Makevars** file and a **Makevars.win** file containing `PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)` and `PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)`. These files must be in the **src** directory.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent My understanding was with the new version of Rcpp, this isn't necessary. It's quite possible I've been misunderstanding something though...

Comment: This is the way I'm using for one of my packages. I have not submitted to CRAN the version using OpenMP yet but I've tested on **R-hub** and got no issue.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I have no issue on rhub either. RE: Rcpp, I was using this information from https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-package.pdf. "Now optional: Makevars and Makevars.win This behaviour changed with Rcpp release 0.11.0. These files used to be mandatory, now they are merely optional"

Comment: That depends. For example a Makevars file is needed for a package using RcppArmadillo, because you have to tell to the compiler that your C++ code uses LAPACK. You are scaring me now, I'm fearing I will encounter the same problem with my package.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54062116/1100107). Dirk Eddelbuettel does not mention that the Makevars file is not mandatory for OpenMP usage.

Comment: That's fair enough. I am happy add Makevars and Makevars.win files. CC @DirkEddelbuettel